# A two-column card-based layout for desktop and mobile using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a two column html structure like the following picture:

[image]

The numbers inside each box means the order of the `div's` in the html markup.

The challenge is that I want to have a different sort order on a mobile device. For example, on a mobile device, number 4 should be below number 1 without changing the html. I think using `flexbox` should be the best way to achieve this. But I couldn't make it work.

Using `floats` isn't the way, because at the first side when there is some space, the next `div` will automatic float to that side.

I also cannot make extra wrapper's for each column, because using `order` will not work then.

Does somebody has an idea?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style="height:200px;" class="item">1</div>
  <div style="height:150px;" class="item">2</div>
  <div style="height:100px;" class="item">3</div>
  <div style="height:50px; float:right;" class="item">4</div>
  <div style="height:75px; float:right;" class="item">5</div>
  <div style="height:150px; float:right;" class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below features:

- A column-direction flex container
- Flex items wrap at viewport height
- On smaller screens (based on height or width), the fourth item moves to the second position in the visual order, and the items align in a single full-width column.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.item {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}

@media ( max-width: 500px ), ( max-height: 500px ) {
    .row { flex-direction: row; }
    .item { flex-basis: 100%; }
    .item:nth-child(1) { order: -2; }    
    .item:nth-child(4) { order: -1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div style="height:200px;" class="item">1</div>
    <div style="height:150px;" class="item">2</div>
    <div style="height:100px;" class="item">3</div>
    <div style="height:50px;" class="item">4</div>
    <div style="height:75px;" class="item">5</div>
    <div style="height:150px;" class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

### [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2eu1wrx9/3/)

Comment: Thanks so far! Why are the items on a smaller screen showing in a row? I didn't tell in my question, but I want to have a two column structure on desktop and one column on mobile device. Where number 4 (for example) should be showing as second.

Comment: First media query covered screen width. I added a second media query to cover screen height.

Comment: If I am right, only when there is no space anymore on the screen height or row height, then there will be a second column? I want to have on a desktop device, that number 4 should be placed at the top of the right column and number 5 below 4, etc.

Comment: I revised the demos. Hopefully it works now. Otherwise let me know.